# How to see the output of Console application when running with WSL2 profile?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, wsl-2

I have written a simple console application targeting .Net5. It's working as expected. I am running the application with the WSL 2 profile now. It's running successfully, but not showing output as it shows for the normal console application (I mean it is not showing the window itself). It is hitting the breakpoint as well.
Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2019) article, My understanding is we can debug the application in Linux from a Windows machine.

So how can I see the output of the console application? Also, does it create any folder or files in Linux?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I am not using docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click Debug->windows->output to show the output.

[image]

Then, you can choose where you want to show the output.

[image]

Comment: It is showing `Hello` when I chose Show output from value as `Debug`